# SSL certificate renewal

Tags: ssl, centos, certificate, ssl-certificate, digital-ocean

I have a website which certificate expired today, and I need to renew it but I need help.
I added a new certificate on my digitalocean account that's supposed to expire in April but it still says that my certificate expired on my website.
What else do I need to do to renew my certificate?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Did you reload apache/nginx?  The config for apache (what I tend to use) will not be reread until you either stop then start or do a restart (systemctl restart httpd)